# Database access in struts 2

Tags: java, jdbc, struts2, persistence

I am using JDBC drivers in java action class file to access database in struts 2. But as mentioned on [this](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.8/faqs/database.html) website there is another way to access database in struts using  tag in `struts.xml` file. But that is not working for me in struts 2. My question is is there any other more efficient way to access database in struts2 other than using JDBC drivers because I have to make connection each time I access any action class file? And I am not using hibernate only want to use Struts.

Comment: please check, if you are using struts1 or struts2

Comment: It shouldn't really matter. If you want efficient db access then you should probably use connection pooling, your container should be able to provide this for you. Depending on the implementation will change how it is used. This has very little to do with struts btw, as a matter of fact people often insulate these details behind a serivce layer.  When looking at the web tier you should not be able to identify any db/persistence logic. fwiw there I think there are some jdbc tag libraries out there... so you can still get the functionality, although using them would be very un-action!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Java EE Web Application, database connections should be managed and pooled inside an EJB, the war should know nothing about the datasource or the database connection details.

If you can choose which technology to include in your Web App, I strongly suggest to let Spring manage your database connections.

[Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_spring.htm) of Struts2 + Spring integration.

Note: Spring libraries have nothing to do with Spring MVC, that is a framework alternative to Struts2.

---

> **Edit**
>
> Things change and nowadays for persistence / ORM I suggest pure **Java EE**'s **JPA2** over Spring.